# How can i apply java script to access the client id or a control placed in the grid view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to access a dropdown asp control client id placed in the gridview.

```
function validate(){
 var ddl = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdProducts_ctl02_ddlSelectSize");
}
```

I want a generalized way to access above id on a rowcommand event click of a gridview that holds a button.
And onButton click i am calling method `onclientClick(return validate());`

Comment: Could you provide some more details? I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a marker css class to you dropdown. Than you can search for all inputs which have this class and attach to click event.

Attached event handler method has the information about sender so that you do not have to hardcode anything.

If you can use jQuery it gets really simple. I can provide you a sample code if you need

Answer (score 1):

try this code,will work fine

```
      var grid = document.getElementById(gridID); 
    var ddl= grid.rows[1].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Comment: i can't hard code the row number, because i need to access it for all the rows.